# How to pass dynamically generated ids to jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

**Consider this snippet:**

```
<a href="profile.php?viewuserprofile=45">
  <img style="width: 15% !important;" class="tableimg" src="core/uploads/321344.jpg" alt="profilename">
</a>
<br><br>

<textarea id="chatMessage2" name="chatMessage" style=" padding: 2%; width: 100% !important; background:#d4d4d4; border:0;" placeholder="Type your message here... " value=""></textarea>
<button id="buttons2" type="submit" name="sendChat" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Send</button>
<input id="fromUserId2" name="fromUserId" value="45" type="hidden">
<input id="toUserId2" name="toUserId" value="45" type="hidden">
```

How do I make the dynamic ids available to jQuery? I generate all dynamically with php while statement. Basically all ids will be dynamic.

**EDIT FULL JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#buttons").click(function(){
var fromuserid = $("#fromUserId").val();
var touserid = $("#toUserId").val();
var chatMessage = $("#chatMessage").val();
// stored in database.
var dataString = 'fromUserId='+ fromuserid + '&toUserId='+ touserid + '&chatMessage='+ chatMessage;
// AJAX
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "chat.php",
data: dataString,
cache: true,
success: function(response){
   $("#displayMessage").html(response);
       $("#chatForm").trigger("reset");
}
});

return false;
});

});
 $(document).ready(function(e){ $.ajaxSetup({cache:false}); 
setInterval(function(){$('#displayMessage').load('log.php');}, 3000); 
});
    </script>
```

Comment: using this context on event

Comment: @guradio: ok thanks. Mind to elaborate?

Comment: for example on click event use `$(this)` to get the clicked element

Comment: @guradio: im a newbie to jQuery... I need to be taught by example :-/

Comment: show your whole code of JS

Comment: @guradio: edit made

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145399/discussion-between-guradio-and-sebastian-farham).

Comment: If you find yourself generating sequential element IDs in a loop you should consider refactoring to use common classes for those elements instead, and then in associated JS event handlers use DOM navigation methods to select whichever elements are related to the one the event happened to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you are generating same elements instead of using ID use class.
2. Use `$(this)` this context to get the information related to clicked button

Simple Demo below:

```js
$('.buttons').click(function() {

  var text = $(this).closest('.row').find('textarea.chatMessage').val();
 var fromUserId = $(this).closest('.row').find('input.fromUserId').val();
 var toUserId = $(this).closest('.row').find('input.toUserId').val();
  var q = text + " fromUserId = " + fromUserId + " toUserId = " + toUserId
  $(this).closest('.row').find('div.displayMessage').text(q)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
  <textarea class="chatMessage" name="chatMessage" style=" padding: 2%; width: 100% !important; background:#d4d4d4; border:0;" placeholder="Type your message here... " value=""></textarea>
  <button class="buttons" type="submit" name="sendChat" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Send</button>
  <input class="fromUserId" name="fromUserId" value="45" type="hidden">
  <input class="toUserId" name="toUserId" value="45" type="hidden">

  <div class="displayMessage" style="">

  </div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
  <textarea class="chatMessage" name="chatMessage" style=" padding: 2%; width: 100% !important; background:#d4d4d4; border:0;" placeholder="Type your message here... " value=""></textarea>
  <button class="buttons" type="submit" name="sendChat" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Send</button>
  <input class="fromUserId" name="fromUserId" value="46" type="hidden">
  <input class="toUserId" name="toUserId" value="46" type="hidden">

  <div class="displayMessage" style="">

  </div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
  <textarea class="chatMessage" name="chatMessage" style=" padding: 2%; width: 100% !important; background:#d4d4d4; border:0;" placeholder="Type your message here... " value=""></textarea>
  <button class="buttons" type="submit" name="sendChat" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Send</button>
  <input class="fromUserId" name="fromUserId" value="47" type="hidden">
  <input class="toUserId" name="toUserId" value="47" type="hidden">

  <div class="displayMessage" style="">

  </div>
</div>
```